# os.walk() different behaviour if directory names are referred to

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, python-os

I'm learning Python and writing an application which will recurse a folder tree and identify files of a particular extension.

The test folder structure is as follows, there are 10 text files in it:

```
C:\TEMP\ROOT
├───dir1
│   │   dir1file1.txt
│   │   dir1file2.txt
│   │
│   ├───subdir1
│   │       dir1subdir1file1.txt
│   │       dir1subdir1file2.txt
│   │
│   └───subdir2
│           dir1subdir2file1.txt
│           dir1subdir2file2.txt
│
└───dir2
    │   dir2file1.txt
    │   dir2file2.txt
    │
    └───subdir1
        │   dir2subdir1file1.txt
        │
        └───subdir1
            └───subdir1
                    dir2subdir1subdir1subdir1file1.txt
```

The business end of the code, extracted and simplified is:

```
def scan_for_txt_files(start_from):
    for root_path, subdirs, files in os.walk(start_from):
        for _ in subdirs:
            # In the real application I update a progress bar here.
            for this_file in files:
                ext = str.lower(os.path.splitext(this_file)[1]).replace('.', '')
                if ext == 'txt':
                    print(f'{os.path.join(root_path, this_file)}')
```

When run it prints:

```
c:\temp\root\dir1\dir1file1.txt
c:\temp\root\dir1\dir1file2.txt
c:\temp\root\dir1\dir1file1.txt
c:\temp\root\dir1\dir1file2.txt
c:\temp\root\dir2\dir2file1.txt
c:\temp\root\dir2\dir2file2.txt
c:\temp\root\dir2\subdir1\dir2subdir1file1.txt
```

However if I amend the code to remove the reference to the subdirs it works correctly:

```
def scan_for_txt_files(start_from):
    for root_path, subdirs, files in os.walk(start_from):
        for this_file in files:
            ext = str.lower(os.path.splitext(this_file)[1]).replace('.', '')
            if ext == 'txt':
                print(f'{os.path.join(root_path, this_file)}')
```

Output:

```
c:\temp\root\dir1\dir1file1.txt
c:\temp\root\dir1\dir1file2.txt
c:\temp\root\dir1\subdir1\dir1subdir1file1.txt
c:\temp\root\dir1\subdir1\dir1subdir1file2.txt
c:\temp\root\dir1\subdir2\dir1subdir2file1.txt
c:\temp\root\dir1\subdir2\dir1subdir2file2.txt
c:\temp\root\dir2\dir2file1.txt
c:\temp\root\dir2\dir2file2.txt
c:\temp\root\dir2\subdir1\dir2subdir1file1.txt
c:\temp\root\dir2\subdir1\subdir1\subdir1\dir2subdir1subdir1subdir1file1.txt
```

The first form of the code is because my intention is to determine the number of subfolders beforehand, and then in the 'for ... in subdirs' section, update a progress bar based on how many folders have been scanned.

This happens either with the real filesystem or pytest\pyfakefs. I'm sure it's something simple but I can't grasp what's going on.

Comment: Why would you expect the code to need to reference `subdirs` (when your goal is only to iterate over files, and doesn't actually involve knowing what subdirectories each `root_path` has)? It's not obvious to my why the initial attempt would be _expected_ to be correct.

Comment: ...when you iterate over subdirs, you're running everything inside that loop body a variable number of times (depending on how many subdirs there _are_). Why is that behavior you want?

Comment: Are we seeing the output of the simplified script ot the original? The first one shows duplicates, which we would expect because the code `for _ in subdirs:` has the file processing happen for each subdirectory. That seems like a bizzare thing to do. But the lack of subdirectories suggests that you are in fact changing the `subdirs` list, which will change what os.walk does.

Comment: Can you make this a running script that creates the directory tree for test>

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Because as per the comment in the first code block I want to update a progress indicator on a folders scanned out of total folders basis.#

Comment: @tdelaney I'm not updating the lists. The directory tree exists, exactly the same both in the real filesystem and using pyfakefs in my tests.

Comment: @AlanB, but `dirs` doesn't tell you anything useful about what percentage of folders have been scanned. It tells you how many subdirectories the current root_dir has, but that doesn't tell you how many subdirectories there are total -- so I don't see how it's useful for progress-bar maintenance.

Comment: It does if I previously used os.walk() to count them, I didn't include that code to keep the listing shorter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with my incomplete understanding of Python generators and also incorrect indentation on my part. The 'for this_file in files' section should be indented at the same level as the 'for _ in subdirs' section.

Thanks for the replies.